# Returning local variables without copying them

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and would like to know if there is a way to create an object in a function and then return that object without it having to be copied in memory. 
I know the original local object goes out of scope, but I hoped the compiler could optimize it in a way that the copy of the object would just reuse the same memory adress.

```
int foo()
{
    int bar = 5;
    std::cout << &bar << std::endl;

    return bar;
}

int main()
{
    char a;
    auto b = foo();
    std::cout << &b << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

This returns different memory addresses. Since the address of bar is no longer needed and b is always the same size, is there any reason it couldn't just use the same address and save the step of copying?

---

It doesn't really matter for a simple integer but for larger Objects, what would be the preferred way to make sure the returned object does not get copied in memory?

Would the following be a good approach?

```
int & foo(int & bar)
{
    std::cout << &bar << std::endl;
    // do things with bar
    return bar;
}

int main()
{
    char a;
    auto bar = 5;
    auto & b = foo(bar);
    std::cout << &b << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

---

As a side question, why does the following thing work:

```
int & foo()
{
    int bar = 5;
    std::cout << &bar << std::endl;

    return bar;
}

int main()
{
    char a;
    auto & b = foo();
    std::cout << &b << " " << b << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that bar is out of scope and could no longer be referred to, but this compiles and returns the correct value (MSVC++ 2013).

Comment: The question indicated as a duplicate deals with large objects. I think the OP here is more interested specifically in the `int` case.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The emphasis seems to be the cost of copying, but it really makes no difference if you have `int` or `BigObject`, which should be clear from answers to the duplicate or this question. But I am happy to re-open this if deemed useful.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, actually, I would not be able to tell the OP why e.g. VC does not optimise away the `int` copy with full optimiation flags. If you replace `int` with `std::string`, the same address will be printed. I suspect that such an optimisation would somehow be pointless, so I hoped to see some enlightening responses specifically on that aspect. (OTOH, I may be interpreting too much into the OP's question here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It doesn't really matter for a simple integer but for larger Objects, what would be the preferred way to make sure the returned object does not get copied in memory?

Just return the object. C++ has [*return value optimization* which means the copy can be (and most often is) elided](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

```
big_object get_object()
{
    big_object bo;
    ....
    return bo;
}

....

big_object big = get_object(); // big gets built in-place
```

If you look at the address of `bo` inside the function and `big` outside, you would expect to see the same address (although RVO is an optimization that *can* happen, but doesn't *have* to, so there are other factors that could influence whether you see the same address. With recent g++ and clang++ I get the same address for objects of size `8` bytes, but not for size `4`.) For example, this produces the same address on clang++ 3.5:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo { int i[2]; };

foo make_foo()
{
  foo f;
  std::cout << &f << std::endl;
  return f;
}

int main()
{
  foo f = make_foo();
  std::cout << &f << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I must say I'm somewhat confused by you both answering and dupe-closing the question...

Comment: @Angew I found the dupe after searching. But there are  a few wrong answers here so I want to leave a correct one for the time being.

Comment: I wouldn't really mind, except that I had quite an elaborate answer seconds from posting... ;-)

Comment: @Angew Oh OK, sorry about that. I could re-open (I suspect you could too.)

Comment: Nah, the dupe's got it covered. There's also an answer on it which mentions move semantics, so I think it's good enough.

Comment: thanks! Just out of curiosity, I tried compiling in release mode with full optimization, and the addresses are still different. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @BoshWash I'd say the compiler doesn't bother for something as lightning-fast to copy as an `int`. The cost of that copy must be totally dominated by the function call overhead.

Comment: You are right, it works with larger objects. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler follows the C++ standard, there's no need to use strange code: the compiler is in fact allowed (according to the standard) to optimize the returning of values from functions, omitting any copy (just Google "c++ return value optimization").
This way, you can even return big structures on the stack by value, without worrying.

EDIT: Answer corrected, thanks to juanchopanza.

Comment: The "compiler" could optimize away copies when returning by value way before C++11. Return value optimization has existed for a long time.

Comment: So technically this is correct, but misleading (suggests RVO doesn't work before C++11.)

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, I confused rvo with r-value references. I'll change the answer accordingly.